# Postgres - get working hours per shift from timestamp records

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, range

So I have a Postgres table structure like this:

```
id|data         |start_at               |end_at                 |contractor|
--+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------+
 1|first insert |2022-11-22 08:00:00.000|2022-11-22 18:30:00.000|         1|
 2|second insert|2022-11-22 17:00:00.000|2022-11-22 23:30:00.000|         1|
 3|third insert |2022-11-22 22:00:00.000|2022-11-23 05:30:00.000|         1|
 4|fourth insert|2022-11-22 22:00:00.000|2022-11-23 05:30:00.000|         1|
 5|fifth insert |2022-11-21 19:30:00.000|2022-11-22 04:30:00.000|         1|
```

I also know there are three working shifts:

- Morning (from 06:00 to 14:00)
- Afternoon (from 14:00 to 22:00)
- Night (from 22:00 to 06:00 morning the next day)

I need to do a select that will give me total time per shift for each day depending on the inserted timestamps, for example:

```
id|data         |start_at               |end_at                 |contractor|morning|afternoon|night|
--+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------+-------+---------+-----+
 1|first insert |2022-11-22 08:00:00.000|2022-11-22 18:30:00.000|         1|      6|        4|    0|
 2|second insert|2022-11-22 17:00:00.000|2022-11-22 23:30:00.000|         1|      0|        6|    1|
```

I have no problem extracting total work hours, like this:

```
extract(hour from age(t.end_at  ,t.start_at)) as total_work_hours
```

but I'm not sure how to go about this particular case. Any help would be welcomed.

I tried converting the start_at and end_at timestamps to minutes after midnight, and then treating the while thing as a range of integer numbers with CASE statements, but that whole thing looks like a mess and I would like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is a bit verbose but basically calculates the beginning end the end of the period *within* the corresponding shift (using greatest and least), calculates the period length in seconds and divides by 3600 and then sets the negative values to zero. Note the `+ 1` in the night shift end expression. [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qqsSQonCj75DAeXcQU4qmj/0)

```sql
with t as
(
select *, 
 extract ('epoch' from 
    least   (end_at,   start_at::date + '14:00'::time) 
  - greatest(start_at, start_at::date + '06:00'::time)) / 3600 first_shift,
 extract ('epoch' from 
    least   (end_at,   start_at::date + '22:00'::time) 
  - greatest(start_at, start_at::date + '14:00'::time)) / 3600 second_shift,
 extract ('epoch' from 
    least   (end_at,   start_at::date + 1 + '06:00'::time) 
  - greatest(start_at, start_at::date + '22:00'::time)) / 3600 third_shift
from the_table
)
select id, data, start_at, end_at, contractor, 
       case when first_shift > 0 then first_shift else 0 end morning, 
       case when second_shift > 0 then second_shift else 0 end afternoon,
       case when third_shift > 0 then third_shift else 0 end night
from t;
```

| id | data | start_at | end_at | contractor | morning | afternoon | night |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first insert | 2022-11-22 08:00:00.000 | 2022-11-22 18:30:00.000 | 1 | 6.0 | 4.5 | 0.0 |
| 2 | second insert | 2022-11-22 17:00:00.000 | 2022-11-22 23:30:00.000 | 1 | 0.0 | 5.0 | 1.5 |
| 3 | third insert | 2022-11-22 22:00:00.000 | 2022-11-23 05:30:00.000 | 1 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 7.5 |
| 4 | fourth insert | 2022-11-22 22:00:00.000 | 2022-11-23 05:30:00.000 | 1 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 7.5 |
| 5 | fifth insert | 2022-11-21 19:30:00.000 | 2022-11-22 04:30:00.000 | 1 | 0.0 | 2.5 | 6.5 |